# How can I do to convert OrderedDict to Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

I have a this list

```
a = [OrderedDict([('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e', OrderedDict([('a','b'), ('c','d') ]))])]
```

and I want to convert the OrderedDict in dictionary.

Do you know how could I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: This in not a orderddict, but it is a list of tuples, also you could perhaps do `dict(a)`

Comment: Have you tried giving it a go yourself? Perhaps callining the dict constructor?

Comment: you wrote a list here, then asked about converting an OrderedDict in Dictionary? Can you clarify what is it you need? Also, An OrderedDict can behave like a dictionary without issues, is there a particular reason you're looking to convert the OrderedDict?

Comment: What's the expected output here?

Comment: An `OrderedDict` *is* a `dict`; in what sense do you need to "convert" it?

Answer (score 11):

To convert a nested `OrderedDict`, you could use package `json`

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(a))

[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}}]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I have something like this : `{ValueError}dictionary update sequence element #0 has length x; y is required`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a recursive function to do the conversion from OrderedDict to dict, checking for the datatypes using isinstance calls along the way.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def OrderedDict_to_dict(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, (tuple, list)): #for some iterables. might need modifications/additions?
        return [OrderedDict_to_dict(item) for item in arg]

    if isinstance(arg, OrderedDict): #what we are interested in
        arg = dict(arg)

    if isinstance(arg, dict): #next up, iterate through the dictionary for nested conversion
        for key, value in arg.items():
            arg[key] = OrderedDict_to_dict(value)

    return arg

a = [OrderedDict([('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e', OrderedDict([('a','b'), ('c','d') ]))])]


result = OrderedDict_to_dict(a)
print(result)
#Output:
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}}]
```

However, note that OrderedDicts *are* dictionaries too, and support key lookups.

```
print(a[0]['e'])
#Output:
OrderedDict([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])

a[0]['e']['c']
#Output:
'd'
```

So, you should not need to convert the OrderedDicts to dicts if you just need to access the values as a dictionary would allow, since OrderedDict supports the same operations.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a nested OrderedDict, you could use For:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = [OrderedDict([('id', 8)]), OrderedDict([('id', 9)])]
data_list = []
for i in a:
    data_list.append(dict(i))
print(data_list)
#Output:[{'id': 8}, {'id': 9}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage Python's builtin [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) mechanism.

You can override copying behavior for `OrderedDict` via Python's [`copyreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#module-copyreg) module (also used by [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)). Then you can use Python's builtin [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function to perform the conversion.

```py
import copy
import copyreg
from collections import OrderedDict

def convert_nested_ordered_dict(x):
    """
    Perform a deep copy of the given object, but convert
    all internal OrderedDicts to plain dicts along the way.

    Args:
        x: Any pickleable object

    Returns:
        A copy of the input, in which all OrderedDicts contained
        anywhere in the input (as iterable items or attributes, etc.)
        have been converted to plain dicts.
    """
    # Temporarily install a custom pickling function
    # (used by deepcopy) to convert OrderedDict to dict.
    orig_pickler = copyreg.dispatch_table.get(OrderedDict, None)
    copyreg.pickle(
        OrderedDict,
        lambda d: (dict, ([*d.items()],))
    )
    try:
        return copy.deepcopy(x)
    finally:
        # Restore the original OrderedDict pickling function (if any)
        del copyreg.dispatch_table[OrderedDict]
        if orig_pickler:
            copyreg.dispatch_table[OrderedDict] = orig_pickler
```

Merely by using Python's builtin copying infrastructure, this solution is superior to all other answers presented here, in the following ways:

- Works for more than just JSON data.
- Does not require you to implement special logic for each possible element type (e.g. `list`, `tuple`, etc.)
- `deepcopy()` will properly handle duplicate objects within the collection:

  ```py
  x = [1,2,3]
  d = {'a': x, 'b': x}
  assert id(d['a']) == id(d['b'])

  d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
  assert id(d2['a']) == id(d2['b'])
  ```

  Since our solution is based on `deepcopy()` we'll have the same advantage.
- This solution also converts *attributes* that happen to be `OrderedDict`, not only collection elements:

  ```py
  class C:
      def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
          self.a = a or OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')])
          self.b = b or OrderedDict([(3, 'three'), (4, 'four')])

      def __repr__(self):
          return f"C(a={self.a}, b={self.b})"


  print("original: ", C())
  print("converted:", convert_nested_ordered_dict(C()))
  ```

  ```
  original:  C(a=OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')]), b=OrderedDict([(3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]))
  converted: C(a={1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, b={3: 'three', 4: 'four'})
  ```

---

Demonstration on your sample data:

```py
a = [OrderedDict([('a','b'), ('c','d'), ('e', OrderedDict([('a','b'), ('c','d') ]))])]
b = convert_nested_ordered_dict(a)
print(b)
```

```
[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}}]
```